# How can i do data mining and insert data into sql db?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns:GetTrans>
             <ns:return>

        <ns:return>code: 123
     msg: DOWNLOADED SUCCESSFULLY
     Benef Name: Sofi Anna
     Benef COntact No: null 123
     Benef Address: Tokyo
     Benef Account No: 123456789
     Sender Name: Ronaldo  sis
     Sender Address: jpn
     Sender Contact No:  12345678 null
     Authorized Date: 2014-03-27
     Remarks: null
     Remit Type: cash
     AMount: $5000.0
     Branch Details : abc York</ns:return>

      <ns:return>code: 123
     msg: DOWNLOADED SUCCESSFULLY=
     Benef Name: Selena Gomez
     Benef COntact No:  123
     Benef Address: New York
     Benef Account No: 987654321
     Sender Name: Messi  sis
     Sender Address: Banglore
     Sender Contact No:  987654321 
     Authorized Date: 2015-01-20
     Remarks: null
     Remit Type: cash
     AMount: $10000.0
     Branch Details : Canada Brisben

     </ns:return>
      </ns:GetTrans>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have these response from APIserver in XML...How can I get each data from respective column because it does not have elements and all data in same node??
I have to insert into SQL like:

```
Benefname Benef address Amount
Sofi      Tokyo        50000
Selena    Japan        10000
```

Comment: What is currently receiving that response? SSIS? A .Net app?

Comment: asp-classic app..

Comment: This isn’t data mining. You just need to use an xml library or regular expressions to extract the nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi a different way i solution.
copy+paste your xml code and create veri.xml

[image]

I m asp code vbscript

```
<% @ LANGUAGE = VBScript %>
<%
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
rootPath = Server.MapPath("veri.xml")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(rootPath,1)%>


<%
'Null value skipline

objFile.SkipLine
objFile.SkipLine
objFile.SkipLine
objFile.SkipLine
objFile.SkipLine
'____

 Do  Until objFile.AtEndOfStream


    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    strLine=replace(strLine,"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">","")
    strLine=replace(strLine,"<soapenv:Body>","")
    strLine=replace(strLine,"<ns:GetTrans>","")
    strLine=replace(strLine,"<ns:return>","")


    strLine=replace(strLine,"</soapenv:Body>","")
    strLine=replace(strLine,"</ns:GetTrans>","")
    strLine=replace(strLine,"</ns:return>","")
    strLine=replace(strLine,"</soapenv:Envelope>","")




    strLine=replace(strLine," code",";code")

    alanlar = Split(strLine, ";")
    adet = Ubound(alanlar)

    For i = 0 To adet
        response.write ("<br>") 

        Response.Write alanlar(i)
    Next


Loop

objFile.Close
%>
```

And result

[image]

you can configure yourself

Comment: its just amazing thnks dude